# What font does macOS Mojave use?

Tags: mojave, font, menu-bar

What font is used in the macOS Mojave GUI? I am specifically looking for the font on the Menu bar.

I did find another post here, but it only showed the fonts for the old MacOS versions.
[What's the font in Mac OS X's GUI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12661/whats-the-font-in-mac-os-xs-gui/12663)

The reason I am posting this question is because I am not sure if the font has changed after Mac OS El Capitan.

Comment: The dupe is still valid to Mojave. I updated the info there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system font used in the current version of Apple's software platforms is called San Francisco. It is a sans-serif typeface which is developed by Apple. It was first released in 2014. It is a proprietary in nature.

You can learn more about the typeface by checking these links:

- [Fonts - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/)
- [Typography - Visual Design - macOS - Human Interface Guidelines - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/visual-design/typography/)
- [San Francisco (sans-serif typeface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(sans-serif_typeface))

From the Wikipedia page:

> It was the original system typeface of watchOS and tvOS and has replaced Helvetica Neue and Lucida Grande as the system typeface of macOS and iOS since OS X El Capitan and iOS 9
>
> Apple restricts the usage of the typeface by others. It is licensed to registered third-party developers only for the design and development of applications for Apple's platforms